# JAVA Spring to MS Azure Logic App and Functions

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cloud, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am exploring options how to convert my existing java application which has Sprint framework to Azure Cloud server less "Logic App" and "Functions" concept
**without re-writing.**

As far as i can see, there is no accurate information in microsoft websites.

Can any one please suggest me on the road map, that, how i must lift and shift my java spring frame work to Azure Function?

I am aware of the fact that there will be little modifications that i might need to do, that is ok with me. But not a complete re-write into some other language.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly but with the new Java support as long any package you are using can be resolved with Maven it should work in Functions.  The potential bigger question is what can remain as-is.  Likely each of your controller methods would become Azure Functions - the method signature would change but the code inside should remain largely the same (HttpTrigger with a request message to a route).  The models should be able to stay untouched.  If you had any orchestration or workflows that would become orchestrated by Logic Apps - but since Logic Apps has no-code, it would mean re-creating that workflow/orchestration in Logic Apps.

Java is still in preview so you may hit some snags here and there, but let us know if you have any other questions along the way.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Let me have a look at it.

Besides, i am using Logic Apps to build the work flow. My requirement is to pull the files from FTP server automatically when a file is added in FTP Server. Here, most of the MS docs talks about the Classic Windows VM endpoint setting, but not Resource manager firewall setting for passive FTP server settings on azure. I am getting Time Out error in Logic App FTP connector.

Can you please help me here with any link?
I referred below link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2013/12/12/setting-up-a-passive-ftp-server-in-windows-azure-vm/

Comment: I don’t believe passive is supported for the logic apps FTP trigger. Also if looking for an FTP server to quickly deploy and use if you deploy any Azure App Service (like a website) it will come with a FTP server you can use to upload files and test.